# Converting multiple strings into JSON arrays

Tags: php, json

I have multiple strings that looks like the following: `11-16`, `16-12`, `14-16`

I will have multiple of these, and I need to store them in JSON. I need to store it in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "score_1": 11,
    "score_2": 16
  },
  {
    "score_1": 16,
    "score_2": 12
  },
  {
    "score_1": 14,
    "score_2": 16
  }
]
```

with `score_1` being the first number, and `score_2` being the second number. How will I be able to do this in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an array. Next create an object, then [explode](http://php.net/explode) the string on the hyphen and store the [intval](http://php.net/intval)'d first and second number in the object. Push that object into your array. Repeat for as many strings as you have. Finally, use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) to get a JSON-encoded string.

```
$arr = [];

function addString($str, &$arr) {
    $str = explode("-", $str);
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->score_1 = intval($str[0]);
    $obj->score_2 = intval($str[1]);
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

addString("11-16", $arr);
addString("16-12", $arr);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Output:**

> [{"score_1":11,"score_2":16},{"score_1":16,"score_2":12}]

---

**Edit:** Updated the above code to use `intval` as the OP has integers in his object in the expected output.

Comment: If you already do their homework, also add the missing conversion to an integer.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Good eye. I've updated the answer to properly convert to integers

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. Convert the strings to the according data structure (e.g. array of stdClass objects).
2. Convert that data structure to JSON.

Note: Since you already know the output you want, you could parse that output to get an idea how its representation in PHP would look like, as a suggestion for the results of the first step.